# Django Rest Framework: Generate BrowsableAPIRenderer form in function-based view

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Is it possible to annotate a DRF function-based view to display an interactive form based on a Serializer?

My view doesn't require the use of a Model, so I feel like class-based Views/ViewSets aren't the right approach.

This sample code produces a working "BrowsableAPI", but with a generic JSON text field:

```
@api_view(http_method_names=('POST', ))
@renderer_classes((JSONRenderer, BrowsableAPIRenderer))
def push_notifications(request: Request, format=None) -> Response:
    serializer = PushNotificationSerializer(data=request.data)
    serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
    params = serializer.data
    # ...
    return Response()
```

I'd like the form it produces to use the serializer. (As browsable documentation.)

Comment: Did you find any solution for this?

Comment: @blockhead I don't remember what I ended up doing, sorry. I might have rewritten it to be class-based instead